# How to add timedelta into datetime while time is in "00:00:00' using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

Here I have a dataset with date, time and one input column. Here I want to select the time for specific value in input column.  Then I convert that time into "00:00:00'

Then what I want to do is for that time add time delta(hours=5).

I tried a code but it just show me only time. date is missing.

My code:

```
data['date']= pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + " " + data['time'],
                    format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)
mask = data['X3'].eq(7)
data['t1'] = data['date'].mask(mask, data['date'].dt.floor('d'))
print (data['t1'].dtype)
def f(x):
ts = x.total_seconds()
hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
return ('{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}').format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds)) 

data['t1'] = data['t1'].apply(f)


match_time="00:00:00"
T = data.loc[data['t1'] == match_time, 't1']
```

output :

```html
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
```

But what I expected output is :

```html
         datetime                     expected output
10/3/2018 6:15:00         10/3/2018 00:00:00
10/3/2018 7:45:00         10/3/2018 00:00:00
10/3/2018 9:00:00         10/3/2018 00:00:00
10/3/2018 9:25:00         10/3/2018 00:00:00
```

Subset of my csv file :

```html
date time X3
10/3/2018 6:15:00  7
10/3/2018 6:45:00  5
10/3/2018 7:45:00  7
10/3/2018 9:00:00  7
10/3/2018 9:25:00  7
10/3/2018 9:30:00  5
10/3/2018 11:00:00 7
10/3/2018 11:30:00 7
10/3/2018 13:30:00 7
10/3/2018 13:50:00 5
10/3/2018 15:00:00 7
10/3/2018 15:25:00 7
10/3/2018 16:25:00 7
10/3/2018 18:00:00 7
10/3/2018 19:00:00 5
10/3/2018 19:30:00 7
10/3/2018 20:00:00 7
10/3/2018 22:05:00 7
10/3/2018 22:15:00 5
10/3/2018 23:40:00 7
10/4/2018 6:58:00  7
10/4/2018 13:00:00 7
```

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

Error:

```html
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-dec077bca7c3> in <module>()
     16     return ('{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}').format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds))
     17 
---> 18 data['t1'] = data['t1'].apply(f)
     19 
     20 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3190             else:
   3191                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3192                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3193 
   3194         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-49-dec077bca7c3> in f(x)
     11 
     12 def f(x):
---> 13     ts = x.total_seconds()
     14     hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
     15     minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)

AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
```

Comment: How working if change `T = data.loc[data['t1'] == match_time, 't1']` to `T = data[data['t1'] == match_time]` ?

Comment: @jezrael hello friend , when I applies your code it gave me this error "'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'"

Comment: @jezrael Here I add the error also

Comment: yes, problem is you cannot convert timedeltas to strings...

Comment: @jezrael Then what I have to do ? Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @jezrael I corrected it. But it came as similar as "00:00:00" , and data length also less, I want to keep my data  length same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really not sure what problem you want fixed or what your goal is, but what you're saying you want to do can be done. But you're already given the answer in the question, so I'm not sure where you're getting stuck.

Let's take your first statement:

> Here I have a dataset with date, time and one input column. Here I want to select the time for specific value in input column. Then I convert that time into "00:00:00'

That's what your code already does. I've cleaned it up here and make it executable:

```
# Here I've added the preliminary bits so it's executable.
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", delimiter='\t')
# Here I've fixed the line wrapping, added .str.strip() because your data has trailing
# spaces, and removed dayfirst because it doesn't make sense if you're specifying format
data['date']= pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + " " + data['time'].str.strip(), format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
mask = data['X3'].eq(7)
data['t1'] = data['date'].mask(mask, data['date'].dt.floor('d'))
# And you're done. You can print the results, for example:
data[data['X3'] == 7]['t1']
```

That gives

```
0    2018-03-10
2    2018-03-10
3    2018-03-10
4    2018-03-10
6    2018-03-10
7    2018-03-10
8    2018-03-10
10   2018-03-10
11   2018-03-10
12   2018-03-10
13   2018-03-10
15   2018-03-10
16   2018-03-10
17   2018-03-10
19   2018-03-10
20   2018-04-10
21   2018-04-10
Name: t1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Which shows that all the rows that match your condition now have their time changed to `00:00:00`. Note that pandas decides to suppress showing the time when they're all the same. You can print all the data with `data` to force the time to be printed.

Then you say you want to

> for that time add time delta(hours=5).

That's ambiguous, and since you don't show any attempt at it or include it in your expected output, I can't be sure. But assuming you just want to 5 hours to your datetime column, this will do:

```
data['t1'] = data['t1'] + pd.DateOffset(hours=5)
```

Or if you only want to do it to your selected rows:

```
data.loc[data['X3'] == 7, 't1'] = data['t1'] + pd.DateOffset(hours=5)
```

And then you say

> I tried a code but it just show me only time. date is missing.

Which is what your code (in particular, `f(x)`) does. So if you don't want it to do that, don't use that code.

Hope that helps. What might help more, in future, is to start with a [minimum, reproducible example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There was a bunch of stuff in your question that wasn't helping, and it's likely that as you started to strip it down the the MRE you would find what you wanted anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I hope this answer will help for me too .

Comment: data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", delimiter='\t') In this code I guess we have to remove this part"delimiter='\t" Otherwise it will give error

Comment: The data you provided (under "Subset of my csv file" in your question) is tab delimited. So that `read_csv` command worked for me. Not sure why it gives you an error.